# Pointwise limit of a sequence

Tags: convergence-divergence, pointwise-convergence

gn:[a,b]to real R

[image]

I need to find the pointwise limit of gn and prove it converges uniformly.
I managed to find its pointwise limit which is gn={0     q}. Please can anyone help with the second part. I know the definition of a pointwise function being uniformly convergent and I have no problem with the normal ones but not the ones like this. Any hint will help. Thanks.

Comment: Please write your formula out in [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). This helps other users by making the question easier to search for and in case the image hosting site discontinues.

Answer (score 1):

According to your calculation of pointiwse limit function $g$ (namely, $g(x)=0$ if $x=0$ or $x$ is irrational and $g(x)=\frac 1 q$ if $x=\frac p q$ in its lowest terms) we get $g_n(x)-g(x)=\frac  1 n$ for  all $x$ for all $n$. Hence $g_n \to g$ uniformly.